# jQuery does :hover work for td elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, html-table

I have a HTML Table with a hidden infobox in one of the td elements.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .infobox{
        display: none;
        background-color: #FFDB8F;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 90px;
        height: 84px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foobar</td>
        <td>foobar</td>
        <td class="hover">hover me</td>
        <td class="hover">hover me</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="infobox">The terms foobar, fubar, or foo, bar, baz and qux (alternatively, quux) are sometimes used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation.</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foobar</td>
        <td>foobar</td>
        <td class="hover">hover me</td>
        <td class="hover">hover me</td>
        <td>foobar</td>
        <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to show this infobox when the user hovers over certain td elements. So tried this:

```
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    $('.infobox').show();
},
        function() {
            $('.infobox').hide();
        }
});
```

And this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $sample = $(".hover");
    $sample.each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).is(":hover")) {
            $('.infobox').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.infobox').hide();
        }
    });
}, 200);
```

Both did not work for td elements. What am I missing? Or does `.hover()` simply not work for td elements?

Comment: You cant access pseudo class `:hover` in jQuery. You have to toggle a class like `isHovered`.

Comment: Do you look at the browser's console before asking this?

Comment: yep, can have td hovers - http://jsfiddle.net/zxBLw/

Comment: The extra bracket was a copy&paste error. It seems to be a problem with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a typo, you have an extra `}` on your code.

```
$('.hover').hover(
    function() {$('.infobox').show();},
    function() {$('.infobox').hide();}
    } // <-- remove this
);
```

Except for that, it seems to be working fine.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MQ8N/)

Comment: Ok it seems that it is a problem with firefox. I made an own JSFiddle with my code and it worked as expected. If I run the html file in my browser it doesn't work. The extra } was a copy&paste error.

Answer (score 0):

extra `}` in you hover function. Please look your console before asking question.

```
$('.hover').hover(
            function() {$('.infobox').show();},
            function() {$('.infobox').hide();}
        );
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6uX8/)